# How to display the un promoted to front page link in teaser mode contextual links?

Tags: 7

I'm trying to enhance the frontpage teaser's contextual links. On front page content we click on *Configure link*, and it shows *Edit*, *Delete* and *Node Export* by default.

I'd like to also add a *Unpromote from/to frontpage* link.

Is this possible? If so, how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contextual links can be added by adding a menu item (e.g. [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x) or [`hook_menu_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7.x)) and setting `context` to `MENU_CONTEXT_INLINE` & `type` to `MENU_LOCAL_ACTION`. For node actions, you can add a menu item to the `node/%` route. The nid argument can be passed through so you can execute your appropriate node frontpage toggle logic.

For example:

```
/**
 * implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%/frontpage'] = array(
    'title' => 'Toggle Frontpage Status',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_ACTION,
    'context' => MENU_CONTEXT_INLINE,
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_toggle_frontpage',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('administer content'),
  );
}

function MYMODULE_toggle_frontpage($nid) {
  // @TODO: Add your $node->promote switching logic.

  // Jump back to the original page containing the context menu.
  drupal_goto(drupal_get_destination());
}
```